# Getting a button from Macro in Base (Libreoffice)

Tags: libreoffice, basic, libreoffice-basic, libreoffice-base

I'm trying to create a simple macro to control two buttons that have been placed in a form. They alternate positions, so they can be left pressed or unpressed, and the objective is to have only one of them pressed. My idea was to execute a macro every time one of the two is pressed, and the macro would be in charge of unpressing the other one.

Any ideas?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

The following code is from https://forum.openoffice.org/en/forum/viewtopic.php?f=20&t=34337.  It works for Base forms as well as Calc.

```vb
Sub subButtonDisableButton2(Event As Object)
   Dim oForm As Object
   Dim oModelButton As Object
   'We get the model of the form from the button who calls the macro
   oForm=Event.Source.Model.Parent
   'Now we get the model of button2
   oModelButton=oForm.GetByName("button2")
   'And we disable it!
   oModelButton.Enabled=False
End Sub
```

Or use radio buttons, which typically indicates that only one can be chosen at a time.